# execute function when setting an object

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a function when the value of props.test is changed. I have seen in another question Object.defineProperty can be used. But in my case it will props.test, how to make it work

```
 props.test = props.test || {};
//if props.test value changes it need to execute set function
props.test = "abc";

function setTest(){
console.log("set function is executed");
props.test = "abc";
}
```

Comment: Create a setter and getter for the `.test` property.  That will then execute the setting and getter function each time the property is read or set.

Comment: can you share an example?

Answer (score 4):

This could be achieved by defining [`getter` and `setters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) on an object such as,

```
var props = { 
    get value() { 
       return this._value; 
    }, 
    set value(val) { 
        this._value = val;
        alert("value is: " + val); 
    }
}
```

For the above example, when you set the value on the `props` object, an `alert` function is executed,

```
props.value;           // returns undefined
props.value = "hello"; // alert box will appear, "value is: hello"
props.value;           // returns "hello".
```

This can be replaced with the function you wish to execute when the value changes.

When adding properties onto an existing object you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) like so,

```
var me = {name:'Anthony', location:'RI'};
// let's extend onto the object a new property called, 'age'
// with custom getter and setter
Object.defineProperty(me, 'age', { 
        get: function() { 
                return this._age; 
        }, 
        set: function(newAge) { 
                this._age = newAge;
                alert("I am " + newAge + " now!"); 
        }
});

me.age;        // undefined
me.age = 28;   // alert box will appear, "I am 28 now!"
me.age;        // returns 28.
```

To take it one-step further if the pre-existing object contains an `object`, you can perform the following,

*Note: `Object.defineProperty` takes as arguments an, `object`, `key`, and `descriptor` (ie, our custom setters and getters) respectively. That `object` argument can be any `object` type, even the nested `object` of the parent `object`.*

```
// my pet rules my life, so let's include her in my example object,
var me = {name:'Anthony', location:'RI', pet:{name:'Binks'}};
// let's give her an identifier because that's what good owners do,
// Notice the first argument of, 'me.pet' which is the inner object.
Object.defineProperty(me.pet, 'id', {
        get: function() { 
                return this._id; 
        }, 
        set: function(newId) { 
                this._id = newId; 
                alert("id changed! " + newId); 
        }
});

me.pet['id'];     // undefined
me.pet['id'] = 1; // alert box will appear, "id changed! 1"
me.pet['id'];     // returns 1
```

#### Update: 07/12/2015

If you are trying to add dynamic values onto an `Object`, you can extend the above functionality into a generalized function,

```
var defineProp = function(obj, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, value, {
        get: function() { 
                return this['_' + value]; 
        }, 
        set: function(newValue) { 
                this['_' + value] = newValue; 
                alert(value + " changed! " + newValue); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Only problem is props object is already precreated. So i just somehow attach the "value" without reseting the entire props object.

Comment: @user1595858 If you are not creating the object yourself, you can extend upon it your own properties using `defineProperty` with custom getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question. If i have something like me.age[id]="kslslfj". How can that work?

Comment: @user1595858 When using `defineProperty` the first argument is an object to extend upon, this can also be an object nested within other objects. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Hmm. the problem here is id will be random number that will be assigned such as me.pet['3242424213'] = {name: "Browny"}

Comment: @user1595858 - I had updated my answer to include a generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical way of doing this is to create a function that is responsible for setting the property.  To the best of my knowledge, there is no hook available to monitor when the property of an object has been changed.  Alternatively, you object could use a timer to periodically check to see if the property has changed.